# Texture will absolutely will not work when importing model in blender, why isn't this possible?

Tags: modeling

I have been trying for hours and hours and hours to get this 3D model ready to upload to a website called "The Models Resource" but it's impossible to get the textures to load **with** the model.

The problem is, every time I import the model into Blender, select "material view" and put a lamp on it, it's pink.

[image: Pink box]

But the way I can fix it is by going into the texture menu, and then clicking on the folder and reopening the texture, so it's supposed to look like this

[image: What the box is supposed to look like]

All I want to know is

1. What is the issue that is causing this? Am I not exporting it right? Am I not importing it right?
2. How do I fix it to where the textures will *always* be applied to the box when I import it to Blender.

Comment: Try packing all the textures in the .blend file itself. More details https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/introduction.html

Comment: What format you are importing from? If it is blend file, then you can do what @AshutoshBudhdeo proposed and this will cause texture to be added into the blend file. If you however import it from other formats - like obj, fbx or other, then you should know that texture are usualy not saved into them and need to be applied separately when imported into any 3d software.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures